# preq_replace automatically adds single quote in Thai language

Tags: php, thai

My intention is to breaks groups of 50 chars that do not contain spaces with a `\n`

My code is like this:

```
$string= preg_replace('/([^\s<>]{50})(?=[^\s])/u', "$1\n$2", '[ติดต่อนัดหมายชมโครงการหรือสอบถามข้อมูลเพิ่มเติมที่]');
```

And the result adds `\n` and additional `'` in the new line:

```
[ติดต่อนัดหมายชมโครงการหรือสอบถามข้อมูลเพิ่มเติมที\n
่]
```

But with an arbitrary value:

```
$string= preg_replace('/([^\s<>]{50})(?=[^\s])/u', "$1\n$2", '[ติดต่อนัดหมายชมโครงการหรือสอบถามข้อมูลติดต่อนัดัด]');
```

The result shows without `'`:

```
[ติดต่อนัดหมายชมโครงการหรือสอบถามข้อมูลติดต่อนัดัด\n
]
```

Why does it add additional `'` in the new line ?
How can I avoid it ?